# Web Application Benchmarking

Tags: php, mysql, benchmarking

I have a web application written in PHP using MySQL that I would like to test to see how many users it can handle, how much activity, etc.

What method should I use to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[apache ab might help](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html), [as can sql-bench](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-benchmarks.html). It is however an art in itself to write a good stress test (urls, postvalues, etc.), and highly dependent on the actual project.